# apply a function to a pandas dataframe to create a larger dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(3), 'B': [1,5,9]})
```

I want to apply a function that creates a two output for each element in the `df`.

Specifically, I want to apply the following function to the dataframe:

```
def some_func(x):
    return sin(x), cos(x)
```

So the desired output is a 3x4 dataframe that looks like the following (of course with the corresponding numerical value):

```
sin_A  cos_A  sin_B  cos_B
sin(0) cos(0) sin(1) cos(1)
sin(1) cos(1) sin(5) cos(5)
sin(2) cos(2) sin(9) cos(9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `agg`

```
s = df.agg(['sin','cos'])
s.columns = s.columns.map('_'.join)
s
Out[9]: 
      A_sin     A_cos     B_sin     B_cos
0  0.000000  1.000000  0.841471  0.540302
1  0.841471  0.540302 -0.958924  0.283662
2  0.909297 -0.416147  0.412118 -0.911130
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from math import *
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(3), 'B': [1,5,9]})

# def sin_f():
#     return sin(x)
# def cos_f(x):
#     return  cos(x)


df['sin_A']=df['A'].apply(lambda X: sin(X))
df['cos_A']=df['A'].apply(lambda X: cos(X))
df['sin_B']=df['B'].apply(lambda X: sin(X))
df['cos_B']=df['B'].apply(lambda X: cos(X))
del df['A']
del df['B']
print(df)
```